# Python Sqlalchemy insert Data into multiple tables at once

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i got multiple tables with the same definition and i need to add the same data in each of them. I would like to create a List and use this for add the data.

For now:

```
test1 = Data_1(Test = Test)
session.add(test1)

test2 = Data_2(Test = Test)
session.add(test2)

test3 = Data_3(Test = Test)
session.add(test3)

session.commit()
```

What i would like to have:

```
Sql_Data = (Test = Test) # What could i use?

test1 = Data_1(Sql_Data)
session.add(test1)

test2 = Data_2(Sql_Data)
session.add(test2)

test3 = Data_3(Sql_Data)
session.add(test3)

session.commit()
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all the data in a dictionary and construct your instances from that:

```py
data = {'Test': 'Test'}

classes = [Data_1, Data_2, Data_3]

to_insert = [class_(**data) for class_ in classes]
session.add_all(to_insert)
session.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly :)